# IOS App converts text ending in a .com to a link

Tags: ios, mysql, iphone

We have an iPhone app which reads data from our MYSQL database.  Sometimes we have text on our app, which ends in .com.  Such as:

She was voted Model of the Year by models.com.

We don't want the models.com text to appear as a link, but when using our App, the text is automatically converted to a link.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this programatically you can do it this way:

```
textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeNone
```

These options are also available:

```
UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber
UIDataDetectorTypeLink 
UIDataDetectorTypeAddress
UIDataDetectorTypeCalendarEvent 
UIDataDetectorTypeNone      
UIDataDetectorTypeAll
```

They can be combined like this: UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber | UIDataDetectorTypeLink etc

If using interface builder deselect the checkbox: `Detection: Links`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look for a "Detect Links" checkbox in IB for the TextView you are using to display text.  If you uncheck that it will not detect links... there are other items like phone numbers you may want to also make sure detection is off for.